# MarkAsTouched with true argument returns error in AoT

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using the latest version of Angular (4.2.4) and when I call:

```
control.markAsTouched(true);
```

When I try to compile with angular-cli, I get the following error: `Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ onlySelf?: boolean; }'`

It used to work with angular 4.0.0. How should I pass this argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAsTouched) the `markAsTouched` method is defined as this:

```
markAsTouched(opts?: {onlySelf?: boolean}): void
```

So you should either call it as:

```
control.markAsTouched();
```

or if you don't want to mark all the children of the `Control` (if it has any) as touched as well you should call it like this:

```
control.markasTouched({onlySelf: true});
```